# What is touché in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, idiom

What would be a good translation of "touché" from English to Latin?
Translating the French participle gives *tactus*, but I doubt that will convey the same idea.
Is there an idiomatic Latin expression that could be used in a similar way?
I cannot think of anything better than *bene* or *ita vero*.

Comment: 1. *Touché* - because it's already loan word.

Comment: 2. I would analyze what it's original meaning was, before it was borrowed. It comes from fencing, where a touch by the sword was counted as a point. It has come to mean *a telling blow* or *a telling point*, an acknowledgement of an opponent's argument.

Comment: @andy256. Touché is the perf. pass. part. of toucher, like Italian toccare, Spanish tocar etc., all from “Vulgar” Latin *toccare “to knock into”, originally “to the make the sound ‘toc’”.

Comment: .....Hence I could well imagine a mediaeval swordsman shouting "toccatus!", but I think Joonas is looking for something classical.

Comment: @fdb, I would indeed prefer something classical, but I will accept any era. What I most want is attested use in a similar meaning. *Tactus*, *toccatus* and *touché* are all fine, if they have been used that way. And I'm interested in discussions or arguments, not fencing.

Comment: Check under [granted](https://archive.org/stream/copiouscriticale00smit#page/348/mode/2up).

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I hope that ends up extended to an answer. Having more views on this issue is welcome.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I'm pressed for time, and since it's an old question, I won't hurry, but if it goes too long (> month), do feel free to remind me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Touché", to me, indicates that one is gracefully conceding a point in argument. It can also sound a bit pretentious to use the French loanword instead of plain English "granted".

### With that in mind, I would suggest *synchōrō*.

This is (a transliteration of) the first singular present indicative active of Greek συγχωρέω. It's a verb with many different meanings; depending on context it can mean "combine, meet with" or "get out of the way of, withdraw from". But in rhetoric or debate, it means to concede or grant a point to your opponent. The first singular present indicative was used often in Plato, usually by people trying to argue against Socrates. And using a loanword, especially one which contains a non-native sound ("y"), gives it that slightly pretentious touch.

(Source: LSJ)

Example: Plato's "Republic" 1.335e (translation based on Shorey 1969):

> "So if [someone suggests punishing lawbreakers], then he is no truly wise man. For what he meant is not true. For it has been made clear to us that in no case is it just to harm anyone."
> "*Touché*."

Comment: That's a very clever word for this purpose! Do you know if it has been ever used in Latin?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found any confirmation of Latin use.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this translation: [*συγχωρέω*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dsugxwre%2Fw) is actually a pretty vanilla way of saying, "I agree" in Greek. The distinctive nuance of "touché" is "you're right--my argument was bad."

Answer (score 4):

The Latin expression used by Plautus and then picked up by Erasmus (*Adagia* II, iv, 93), ***rem acu tetigisti***, immediately came to mind as potentially useful in answering your question.

> ***rem acu*** is a way of rendering the idea **"point made"**.   Here, the person is not **"touched"**, but the matter is **"touched by the point of a needle"**,
> i.e. with accuracy.  ***Tetigisti*** is implied, but left out of the
> phrase.
>
> ***acu tactus*** is a more direct way of saying **touché** using the
> same phrase as a basis.

see [Brewer's Dictionary of Phrase and Fable](http://www.bartleby.com/81/14217.html):

> Rem Acu.   You have hit the mark; you have hit the nail on the head.
> Rem acu tetigisti (Plautus). A phrase in archery, meaning, You have
> hit the white, or the bull’s-eye.
>
> “‘Rem acu once again,’ said Sir Piercie.”—The Monastery, chap. > xvi.

See Lewis and Short entry for [***acus, -us***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=acus1&highlight=rem%2Cacu) f. needle. Contrast
is made between literal and figurative meaning.

> ***acu rem tangere***, to touch the thing with a needle, English, to hit the nail on the head

from Plautus, *Rudens*, 1306

> Grip. *Tum tu mendicus es?*
>
> Labr. ***Tetigisti acu.***

See also L & S entry for ***[tango, tetigi, tactum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtango)*** - there are multiple literal and figurative uses meaning to touch, to strike and to affect, among others.

Comment: This means "you're right on the mark"--isn't that quite a different idea from "touché"?

Comment: @brianpck, I see your point.   "Acu tactus" might work. I think saying rem acu (tetigisti) can be a way of condeding a point. Joonas said he would prefer an alternative to "bene" or "ita".

Comment: It might be too much to expect a perfectly matching idiom in Latin. This is certainly a related phrase that one should keep in mind. Thanks for the suggestion!